# Combinatorial proof of the identity:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n {(k^3)} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n {k}\right)^2 $$

How could I approach this problem to make a combinatorial proof?

Comment: A combinatorial sum related:$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)\dots(k+p-1)}{p!}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+p)}{(p+1)!}$$ which is really saying $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k+p-1}p=\binom{k+p}{p+1}$$Exploit the cases $p=3,2,1$

Answer (score -2):

Try induction.  Suppose the statement holds for $n-1$.  To prove it for $n$, write:
$$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \right)^2 = \left( n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \right)^2 = n^2 + 2 n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \right)^2
= 
n^2 + 2 n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k +
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^3.
$$
Now use
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = {(n-1) \, n \over 2}.
$$

Comment: The post asks for a combinatorial proof.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that.